# Is "constexpr if" better than switch statement?

Tags: c++, c++17

C++17 introduces "constexpr if" that is instantiated depending on a compile-time condition.

Does it mean that it's better to use "constexpr if" in template functions rather than switch statement?

For example:

```
template<int val> void func()
{
    if constexpr(val == 0) {} else
    if constexpr(val == 1) {} else
    ...
    if constexpr(val == k) {} else {}
}
// vs
template<int val> void func()
{
    switch (val)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        ...
        case k:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "better." More efficient? That will depend on the compiler implementation. Easier to read? I prefer the switch statement, but that's my subjective opinion.

Comment: Switch is easier to read if each case is a simple integer or enumeration, and you get duplicate checking for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if constexpr` was introduced to eliminate certain branches that are ill-formed if the condition is false. In your case, you are only doing some operations on an `int`, so no branch should be ill-formed if another one is well-formed. It doesn't really make sense to use it.

As said above, using `if constexpr` provides no real advantages besides guaranteeing that the compiler will remove every other branch. But I expect a good compiler with optimizations to do that too with the `switch`, as `val` is a constant when `func` is instantiated.

I would use the `switch` statement, but that's just me. So, choose the one you like.